# How to select Random Element From an Array and Remove it from the List

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know how I can select a number randomly from a list and also remove it from the array for the next time?
For example I have an array as:

```
var items   = new Array( 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );
```

now I would like to pick one item when a Pick button pushed and add the picked value to a div and also remove the picked item from the array so in next Pick button push it wont be there until to select all of items.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Seems like you could break this down into pieces, like figuring out how to generate a random number, and how to get an item at an index in an array, how to add text to a div, and how to remove items from an array. You have a lot of questions here. Not to say that people here can't help, but please have a go at doing it yourself before asking people to write all your code for you.

Comment: Hi Jordan, i do not have problem by adding the value to a div. I have issue by selecting the value from the list and meanwile removing that value from the list as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If shuffling the array doesn't matter :

```
items.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();}).pop();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZd4w/)

**EDIT:**

I should probably have been a little clearer as the fiddle doesn't really take advantage of the shuffling.
The array only needs to be shuffled once to make it random, after that there is no reason to shuffle it again, just pop of the last value:

```
var items   = new Array( 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );

items.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();})

$('#test').on('click', function() {
    var ran = items.pop();
    alert(ran ? ran : 'No more numbers in array');
});
```

[**JSPERF**](http://jsperf.com/return-and-remove-random-item/2)
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pZd4w/1/)

Comment: Sorting seems like a needlessly expensive solution.

Comment: @canon - does it make more sense now

Answer (score 7):

[`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
var items = ["a","b","c","d"];
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
var randomItem = items.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
console.log("random item: %o", randomItem);
console.log("remaining items: %o", items);
```

Comment: Personally, for readability, I would prefer `Math.floor` rather than `| 0` - took me Google search or two to realize that it's bitwise mask... Rarely use such an operator in my day-to-day code.